# Cannot find symbol exception

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Question1{
    void test(String s, int d){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer");
        d = in.nextInt();

        String c="";

        for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
             c = c + s;
        }
    }
}
class Times{
     public static void main(String args[]){

          Question1 q= new Question1();
          q.test(c);
     }
}
```

This is my entire code and it is showing compile time Error : `Cannot find symbol c`. I have searched regarding it and gone through the code but was not able to fix it.

Comment: Does it not show on which line you're getting the error? How about  q.test(c); ?

Comment: yes it is showing in 'c' in the function q.test(c);

Comment: can you do me a favour can u re type  the code and show it to me . i am still confused a bit

Answer (score 1):

The object `c` only exists within the scope of your function `test()`. Calling `test()` with only one parameter would also result in an error, as your function signature requires two arguments (one of type `int` and one of type `String`), which is not provided.

Given that you overwrite the values that would be passed into your function, it would be better to remove the arguments altogether and instead declare `d` and `s` as local variables inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your Times Class :

```
public static void main(String args[]){

          Question1 q= new Question1();
          q.test(c);
     }
```

> `q.test(c);`

First thing  error there is no variable or object `c` in your class Times , So it shows cannot find a symbol.

Secondly the method `test` will take two arguments , it should be called like

```
test(String,int)
```

If you want to get the value of c in Times Class make the `return type` of test method to string and assign it to a variable in Times Class